# Finding surjections from some subsets of $\omega^2$ to $\omega$ many at most countable ordinals without choice.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ordinals

Set $A_k =  \{\gamma \ | \ \omega \cdot k \leq \gamma < \omega \cdot (k+1) \}$, and let $B$ be a  set of ordinals such that $B = \{ \alpha_n \ | \ n \in \omega \}$ where each $\alpha_n$ is an at most countable ordinal. Can we say that a set, $\{g_{\alpha_k} \ | \ k \in \omega \}$, of functions exists, such that each $g_{\alpha_k}$ is a surjection from $A_k$ to $\alpha_k$, without any form of choice? Obviously if these were some arbitrary sets then we would need choice, but since they are ordinals I am not sure if choice is necessary or not.

I needed this fact in one of my assignments in which there was no restriction on the usage of choice, so I used it freely. But now I wonder if it can be done without choice, thank you.

Comment: Instead of thinking about $\omega^2$ as an ordinal coding $\omega\times\omega$, just think of it as $\omega\times\omega$, then you don't need to make $A_k$ into these awkward sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I needed some kind of “levels” in my solution so I made those sets, what would they be if I think about $\omega^2$ as $\omega \times \omega$?

Comment: Just $\{k\}\times\omega$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Right, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If $\omega_1$ is singular, then its cofinality is countable. And this is indeed consistent with $\sf ZF$. Then there is a countable set of countable ordinals, $\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}$ whose supremum is $\omega_1$.

In that situation it follows that there is no way to uniformly enumerate all the $\alpha_n$s. If there would, then their union would be countable.

What is true in $\sf ZF$ is that if $\sup B<\omega_1$, then this is possible. So for the general fact to be true for all countable sets of countable ordinals we need to assume that $\omega_1$ is regular. And for that we need just a bit of choice.

Comment: By the way, what form of choice is “$\omega_1$ is regular” equivalent to?

Comment: No particular form of choice. If you press me really hard, then I'd say "Every countable family of sets of enumerations of countable ordinals admits a choice function".

Comment: I see, thank you.